# Install R on redHat CentOs 7. Several errors and dependencies I'm unable to overcome

Tags: r, centos, redhat, yum

I'm using redhat centos 7 and am attempting to install R:

```
sudo yum install R
```

Returns:

```
Error: Package: R-java-devel-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-devel
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.i686 (centos-base-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
Error: Package: R-java-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-headless
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.i686 (centos-base-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-headless = 1:1.8.0
```

Based on the error message I tried to install java-devel:

```
sudo yum install java-devel
```

Which gives:

```
Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64 is obsoleted by 2000:gd-jdk8-1.8.0_92-fcs.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do
```

How can I install java-devel in order to install R?

[Edit]

Java version:

```
java -version java version "1.8.0_92" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

[Edit]

Have also tried the following:

```
sudo yum install R-java-devel
```

Which gives:

```
Error: Package: R-java-devel-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-devel
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.7.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.i686 (centos-base-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-devel = 1:1.8.0
```

Also tried a specific version:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686
```

Which returned:
"Package 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686 is obsoleted by 2000:gd-jdk8-1.8.0_92-fcs.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do".

How can I overcome these issues? Tag suggestions welcome too.

[Edit]
From comments, here is the output from `yum repolist`

```
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, priorities, versionlock
Determining fastest mirrors
 * epel: mirror.prgmr.com
centos-base-prod                                                                                                             9911/9911
centos-cpm-prod                                                                                                                125/125
centos-epel-prod                                                                                                           15503/15503
centos-extras-prod                                                                                                             402/402
centos-hips-prod                                                                                                                 72/72
centos-itsec-prod                                                                                                                82/82
centos-pbis-prod                                                                                                                 43/43
centos-puppet3-prod                                                                                                            242/242
centos-serverspec-prod                                                                                                           11/11
centos-updates-prod                                                                                                          1348/1348
centos_itsec_prod                                                                                                                82/82
collectd-enterprise                                                                                                            232/232
epel                                                                                                                       12743/12743
gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-scl                                                                                                  1121/1121
gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-tms                                                                                                    163/163
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-base                                                                                                 9911/9911
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-epel                                                                                               15503/15503
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-extras                                                                                                 402/402
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-hips                                                                                                     72/72
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-pan                                                                                                      83/83
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-sensu                                                                                                2113/2113
gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-updates                                                                                              1348/1348
gdsnow                                                                                                                             3/3
gutils                                                                                                                           11/11
prod_centos_7_noarch_gd-snow                                                                                                       3/3
sensu-enterprise                                                                                                             4560/4560
yumrepos                                                                                                                         87/87
repo id                                                  repo name                                                              status
!centos-base-prod/x86_64                                 centos-base-prod                                                       9,910+1
!centos-cpm-prod/x86_64                                  centos-cpm-prod                                                            125
!centos-epel-prod/x86_64                                 centos-epel-prod                                                        15,503
!centos-extras-prod/x86_64                               centos-extras-prod                                                         402
!centos-hips-prod/x86_64                                 centos-hips-prod                                                            72
!centos-itsec-prod/x86_64                                centos-itsec-prod                                                           82
!centos-pbis-prod/x86_64                                 centos-pbis-prod                                                            43
!centos-puppet3-prod/x86_64                              Centos Puppet prod Packages                                                242
!centos-sclo-rh/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                                                       8,090
!centos-serverspec-prod/x86_64                           centos-serverspec-prod                                                      11
!centos-updates-prod/x86_64                              centos-updates-prod                                                    1,347+1
!centos_itsec_prod/x86_64                                centos_itsec_prod                                                           82
!collectd-enterprise/x86_64                              Enterprise Collectd Packages                                             231+1
!epel/x86_64                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                          12,743
!gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-scl                             gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-scl                                              1,121
!gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-tms                             gd-prod-centos-v6-64bit-tms                                                163
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-base                            gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-base                                           9,910+1
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-epel                            gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-epel                                            15,503
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-extras                          gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-extras                                             402
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-hips                            gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-hips                                                72
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-pan                             gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-pan                                               82+1
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-sensu                           gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-sensu                                            2,113
!gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-updates                         gd-prod-centos-v7-64bit-updates                                        1,347+1
!gdsnow                                                  prod_centos_7_noarch_gd-snow                                                 3
!gutils/x86_64                                           GUtils Packages                                                             11
!prod_centos_7_noarch_gd-snow                            prod_centos_7_noarch_gd-snow                                                 3
!prod_centos_7_x86_64_saltstack                          prod_centos_7_x86_64_saltstack                                           76+26
!sensu-enterprise/x86_64                                 Enterprise Sensu Packages                                                4,560
!yumrepos                                                Enterprise Yum Repos Repo                                                   87
repolist: 84,336
```

[edit]

enabled only epel, base and updates repos per comments `yum repolist all`:
[image]

After that I tried again with `sudo yum install R`

This produced:

```
Error: Package: libRmath-devel-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
           Requires: libRmath = 3.5.0-1.el7
           Installed: libRmath-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               libRmath = 3.5.1-1.el7
           Available: libRmath-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
               libRmath = 3.5.0-1.el7
Error: Package: R-java-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
           Requires: R-core = 3.5.0-1.el7
           Installed: R-core-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               R-core = 3.5.1-1.el7
           Available: R-core-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
               R-core = 3.5.0-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
           Requires: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5
           Installing: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5
Error: Package: R-java-devel-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
           Requires: java-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
           Requires: R-core = 3.5.0-1.el7
           Installed: R-core-3.5.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               R-core = 3.5.1-1.el7
           Available: R-core-3.5.0-1.el7.x86_64 (centos-epel-prod)
               R-core = 3.5.0-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
              ~java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-32) = 1:1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7
Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
           Requires: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5
           Installing: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
              ~java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-32) = 1:1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.i686 (centos-updates-prod)
              ~java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless(x86-32) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5
Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
           Requires: java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7.x86_64 (centos-base-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.171-2.6.13.2.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.5.el7
           Available: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.8.el7_5
           Installing: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5.x86_64 (centos-updates-prod)
               java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el7_5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Actually, when I go ```ls -l /etc``` I do see yum.repos.d file, it's just empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183208/discussion-between-user3788685-and-doug-fir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears you have conflicting packages installed from possibly 'odd' locations.

`1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.i686 is obsoleted by 2000:gd-jdk8-1.8.0_92-fcs.x86_64` is telling us that `gd-jdk8` is providing the same thing as `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` but `R` doesn't like that name and wants a proper `java` and `java-devel` package.

First thing you need to do is disable all of these odd repos you have enabled and only use the `epel` `base` and `updates` repos.

If you navigate to; `/etc/yum.repos.d/` you should find a folder full of files. open them up and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` which will disable them.

Now you should be able to `yum erase gd-jdk8` and remove that along with any deps. Then you should be able to do `yum install java-devel` which should give you the correct version.

Once you have done that you will need to downgrade you `R-core` and `libRmath` packages as it appears from our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183208/discussion-between-user3788685-and-doug-fir) you have some how managed to install newer versions of those that `R` also wants.

Do; `yum downgrade R-core libRmath` and say 'yes' to the deps. That should bring you down to the correct version you need.

Lastly do `yum install R` and with a bit of luck it should install for you!

It looks like a lot of packages my be provided by an internal repo or something, as you had a lot of things prefixed 'gd' which are not actually `gd` as people might expect! I'd have a word with your operations/IT team to see what's going on.

Lastly remember you disabled all those other repos - well you may wish to re-enable them now BUT... if you ever do a `yum update` make very sure you know what it's going to do as it might try and replace things with those 'gd' prefixed packages.

Yum did actually tell you what was wrong with the `is obsoleted` line. But granted digging into the deps requires a little more knowledge especially when your not sure what your looking at, and it's not a 'stock' install of CentOS!